# Wpf Listview exception Process is used by some other process

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

i am loading Mp3 Files from folder in Listview. right click option pn listview there is a option of Update tags.when i enter fields data and click update tags it throws ecception Process cant access file it is used by some other process here is my code

```
private void UpdateTagEditor_RegisterActionEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tags = sender as UpdateTags;
    string path = tags.targetPath;
    string comments = tags.txtTagComment.Text;
    string lyrics = tags.txtTagLyrics.Text;
    try
    {
        using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.DefaultVersion = 3;
            TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.ForceDefaultVersion = true;
            TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(path);
            tagFile.Tag.Comment = comments;
            tagFile.Tag.Lyrics = lyrics;
            tagFile.Save();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use taglib, but are you sure `TagLib.File.Create()` doesn't try to create the same file in your `using` statement?

Comment: When i edit Mp3 tags in bulk mode code working fine. now i an loading mp3 files and bind with listview prolem i am facing on right click update option where single file tag udading

Answer (score 0):

What are you using the `Stream` for? Nothing it seems. You are trying to create the file twice. Try to remove the stream:

```
private void UpdateTagEditor_RegisterActionEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tags = sender as UpdateTags;
    string path = tags.targetPath;
    string comments = tags.txtTagComment.Text;
    string lyrics = tags.txtTagLyrics.Text;
    try
    {
        TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.DefaultVersion = 3;
        TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.ForceDefaultVersion = true;
        TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(path);
        tagFile.Tag.Comment = comments;
        tagFile.Tag.Lyrics = lyrics;
        tagFile.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
}
```